# Firebase database Android - check if nickname exists if not create another one until we get a new nickname

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a nickname to each user who login to my app for the first time. The nickname is the user's firstname and I add a number to it from 1 to 9 000 000. For example kevin Bond could get the nickname kevin123456.

I have all the nicknames stored in a node of my firebase database. Two users shouldn't have the same nickname, so I have to check wether the nickname already exists or not in my database. If it already exists, I want to create another nickname until I get a new nickname.

I currently:
- add a listener to the usernickname node
- in onDataChange I have a for loop to create a nickname, then I check if it already exists with dataSnapshot.hasChild(newNickname). If the nickname doesn't exist I do what I want with the nickname and break the for loop, if it exists I loop the for loop to try another nickname. Here is my code:

```
    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("usernickname").orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9000000; i++) {
                final Random random = new Random();
                randomNumberId = random.nextInt(9000000);
                String newNicknameId = mFirstnameId + String.valueOf(randomNumberId);
                //if the nickname already exists we restart the for loop to get a new random number
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(newNicknameId)) {
                    i++;
                    //else if the nickname doesn't exists we create it and stop the loop
                } else if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(newNicknameId)) {
                    //do what I want...
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

My issue is that I currently have to download all the nicknames node or at least all the nicknames beginning with the user's firstname. It is an issue for me because it could cost me a lot in GB downloaded if I have a lot of users :D

I guess I could use datasnapshot.exists() to check if the nickname exists without having to download all the nicknames, but I don't see how to create another nickname if it already exists. I cannot have a for loop outside of the listener and break it inside of the listener when needed.

Do you see what is the best way to create a new nickname for my users?

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach for unique nicknames would be to append a time stamp to the name:

```
username + new Date().getTime();
```

This will add a unique long like `1493808526335` and you can be certain that two users are unlikely to register in the same millisecond with the same name.

Comment: Yes it would be better but I think that firstname + 13 digits is too long for a nickname tht should be sharable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another aproch to check if a user exists. You need to change this line:

```
dataSnapshot.hasChild(newNicknameId);
```

with

```
dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().equals(newNicknameId);
```

In which `userName` is the name of field in which you store the `newNicknameId`, assuming your key -> value pair looks like this: `userName: "newNicknameId"`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final Query query = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().orderByChild("usernickname").equalTo("yourNewNickName");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    //here means the value exist
                    //do whatever you want to do
                } else {
                    //here means the value not exist
                    //do whatever you want to do
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

use this will solve your problem. :)

Comment: My issue there is for datasnashot.exists, in this case I need to get a new user nickname and check if it already exists again. I have to repeat t until I get a nickname that doesn't exists.